# Use AS3 to write IOS like slide up menu

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, actionscript

In an AS3 mobile App, I would like to have a menu of buttons or icons that slides up from the bottom.  Using a SlideViewTransition, I can get part of what I want.

```
var transition:SlideViewTransition = new SlideViewTransition();
transition.direction = ViewTransitionDirection.UP;
transition.mode = SlideViewTransitionMode.COVER;
view.navigator.pushView(ShareView, null, null, transition);
```

This works, but it does not do two things that I need to do.

1) I want the new transition to only go up 1/2 of the screen so that the top part of the screen displays the view underneath.

2) I want the new view that covers to be partially transparent.  By setting the alpha of the incoming view's contentGroup background alpha, the new view is transparent as it comes in. But, once it covers the view underneath the view becomes opaque.

```
this.contentGroup.setStyle('backgroundAlpha', 0.5);
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how I would have a view slide up 1/2 way and be transparent?  I have no idea where to start, view skinning?, or subclass transition?, or use something in flash namespace instead of a spark view.

Answer (score 0):

I decided it would be simplest to just use the lower level ActionScript and do the animation myself using methods that are normally applied to a Sprite, but in this case use a VGroup so that I could add spark elements to it.  The following is the base class I wrote.

```
public class SlideUpDialog extends VGroup {

private var pctHeight:Number;
private var stopHeight:Number;
private var vertIncrement:Number;

public function SlideUpDialog(pctHeight:Number) {
    super();
    this.pctHeight = pctHeight;
    if (stage) {
        addedToStageHandler();
    } else {
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
    }
}
private function addedToStageHandler(event:Event=null) : void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);         
    graphics.beginFill(0xEEEEEE, 0.8);
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight * pctHeight);
    graphics.endFill();
    var bevel:BevelFilter = new BevelFilter(4, -45);
    this.filters = [ bevel ];
    x = 0;
    y = stage.stageHeight;
    stopHeight = y * (1 - pctHeight);
    vertIncrement = y / 2 / 24 / 4;
}
public function open() : void {
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, openFrameHandler);
}
private function openFrameHandler(event:Event) : void {
    if (y > stopHeight) {
        y -= vertIncrement;
    } else {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, openFrameHandler);
    }
}
public function close() : void {
          ... the reverse of open
    }
}
```